# How do you get player to interact with level?

Tags: architecture, oop, game-state

I suffer from this problem where I have say a class called Player and a class called Level. Now the only way I can figure out how to say make the player interact with the level is if I do something like

```
player.input();

level.update(player);
```

I would have to do something like that, but then it gets even more complicated if I have monsters and I need to add them to the level e.t.c., so how do I get the monsters to interact with the player.

So I'm struggling with this basic concept. If I use C it gets rid of this problem as I use extern and I can get the data I want so all I think about is the flow. So in C I can do something like this

```
switch (terrain[u.y + dy][u.x + dx])
{
case WALL:
print_msg("You cannot go there.\n");
return 0;
case FLOOR:
case DOOR:
case STAIRS:
reloc_player(u.y + dy, u.x + dx);
return 1;
}
```

So in here we have Player u and your moving that player around only if it doesn't hit a wall. But, I can do this because I use extern on terrain[][].

I'm really struggling. I don't really want to use C as C++ is easier with SFML and I like classes. I suppose the answer is how do I manage interaction between level, mobs and players?

If I was going to do it now I would do this

```
Game::Game()
{
   level.init();
   player.init();
}

void Game::input()
{
  player.input(level.getLevel()); // so yucky
}

void Game::update()
{
  player.update();
  level.update(player); /// yuck
}

void Game::render()
{
 player.render();
 level.render();
}
```

I could do something like this, but it gets really complicated and everything becomes a mess of passing stuff around. In particularly I need to pass the player method to the level.update() so the level knows the player has moved. Everything gets messy and I feel I can't add into the game. Plus I would need to make the level static or something.

Comment: Can the player be part of the level? Ie the level *owns* player? When you call level.update(), it calls player.update(this)... alternatively, you could do it the other way round, where the player *has-a-reference-to* the level.

Comment: I think this is a terrible title for a good question. "How to get player to interact with level" is incredibly vague; your actual question is more like "How to structure the Player and Level objects so that they can interact?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In object-oriented programming, you expose private data with getter-methods.

When your player-class wants to know the terrain-type of a tile, it would call `level.getTerrain(int x, int y)`. That public function of `class Level` would access the private `terrain` array and returns the value of the terrain tile.

When you don't want the player-class to depend on the level-class (which is not a bad idea at all), you would not make the player-class responsible for performing its own actions. Instead of that you would have a `PlayerController` class which knows both the player and the level. It would first ask the player-class what it wants to do. Then it would check the level to see if it can do that. And then it would decide what the player-class really does and make it perform that action. Some incomplete pseudocode:

```
 public void PlayerController::update() {
     // ask the player what it wants to do
     Action action = player.getCurrentAction();
     if (action == Action.MOVE_RIGHT) {
         // decide what the outcome is
         switch (level.getTerrain((player.getX() + 1, player.getY())) {
             case Terrain.FLOOR:
             case Terrain.DOOR_OPEN:
                 player.moveTo(player.getX() + 1, player.getY());
                 break;
             case Terrain.WALL:
             case Terrain.TREE:                  
                 player.speak("ouch!");
                 player.changeHitPoints(-1);
                 break;
             case Terrain.DOOR_CLOSED:
                 level.setTerrain((player.getX() + 1, player.getY(), Terrain.DOOR_OPEN);
                 break;
         }
     }
 }
```